# What is causing the threads to execute slower than the serial case?

Tags: c++, g++

I have a simple function which computes the sum of "n" numbers.

I am attempting to use threads to implement the sum in parallel. The code is as follows,

```
void Add(double &sum, const int startIndex, const int endIndex)
{
    sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + 0.1;
    }    
}
```

```
int main()
{
    int n = 100'000'000;

    double sum1;
    double sum2;

    std::thread t1(Add, std::ref(sum1), 0, n / 2);
    std::thread t2(Add, std::ref(sum2), n / 2, n);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << "sum: " << sum1 + sum2 << std::endl;

    // double serialSum;
    // Add(serialSum, 0, n);
    // std::cout << "sum: " << serialSum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, the code runs much slower than the serial version. If I modify the function such that it does **not** take in the sum variable, then I obtain the desired speed-up (nearly 2x).

I read several resources online but all seem to suggest that variables must not be accessed by multiple threads. I do not understand why that would be the case for this example.

Could someone please clarify my mistake?.

Comment: I am using g++ without any optimization flags. So the code is compiled simply by g++ -pthread main.cpp -o demo

Comment: Have you tried `O2`?

Comment: Measuring performance without optimising is a waste of time.  Code generation for non-optimised builds is for ease of debugging.

Comment: `I am using g++ without any optimization flags.` That's asking the compiler *not* to make the code run fast. So it doesn't.

Comment: I have tried O2 as you suggested and it seems to provide the correct output in terms of execution time. Note I use time ./demo to check the execution time and for the real time I find the desired x2 speed-up using O2. Why is that?.

Comment: In your "serial" code, do you use the `Add` function then as well? Have you looked at the generated assembly to see what the compiler actually does? Even when building without optimization, the compiler is allowed to do optimizations, and there might be a case for a simple optimization in the serial code which isn't possible with the threaded code.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you for your response. I agree that the compiler will not make any optimizations. I simply wanted to observe the raw gain in speed by using more threads. It seems the compiler will not do that if I do not use any O2 or O3?.

Comment: On another note, your use-case is a bad example for using explicit threads. [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) would be a better solution for your use-case, I think.

Comment: You may have issues with false sharing here btw: try, if aligning the doubles to 64 (or `std::hardware_destructive_interference_size`) makes a difference...

Comment: Simplest way to find out where the time is being used is to profile the code. With modern CPUs performing out of order execution and branch prediction, analysing the generated assembly is error prone unless you are already expert in the CPU architecture.

Comment: @fabian I initialized the values of sum1 and sum2 to 0.0. However, that did not produce the desired effect. Up till now, only the addition of O2 seems to work. I am just wondering why the threads are competing for sum1 and sum2. Note that the code slows down instead of speeding up or staying the same.

Comment: Also remember that the threaded program does so much more than the non-threaded code. Creating a thread, waiting for it to finish, and reap it isn't free.

Comment: @HumayunAhmed sorry, didn't look thoroughly enough. The false sharing issue may still be there though: if both doubles end up in the same cache line, both threads may treat the variables as if it was the same memory location as access synchronization is concerned so accesses may actually do some synchronization with the other thread there...

Comment: @fabian Thank you for clarifying. As far as I understand, the threads may be accessing the same memory location. So far the compiler flag O2 is fixing that. Is there any resource where I can learn more about such conflicts or problems?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is hardware.

You probably know that CPUs have caches to speed up operations. These caches are many times faster then memory but they work in units called cachelines. Probably 64 byte on your system. Your 2 doubles are each 8 byte large and near certainly will end up being in the same 64 byte region on the stack. And each core in a cpu generally have their own L1 cache while larger caches may be shared between cores.

Now when one thread accesses `sum1` the core will load the relevant cacheline into the cache. When the second thread accesses `sum2` the other core attempts to load the same cacheline into it's own cache. And the x86 architecture is so nice trying to help you it will ask the first cache to hand over the cacheline so both threads always see the same data.

So while you have 2 separate variables they are in the same cache line and on every access that cacheline bounces from one core to the other and back. Which is a rather slow operation. This is called false sharing.

So you need to put some separation between `sum1` and `sum2` to make this work fast. See [std::hardware_destructive_interference_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size) for what distance you need to achieve.

Another, and probably way simpler, way is to modify the worker function to use local variables:

```
void Add(double &sum, const int startIndex, const int endIndex)
{
    double t = 0.0;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        t = t + 0.1;
    }    
    sum = t;        
}
```

You still have false sharing and the two threads will fight over access to `sum1` and `sum2`. But now it only happens once and becomes irrelevant.